# ROCR Curve on a stacking model

Tags: r

I'm doing a stacking model and I want to find the ROC Curve for it and RAUC (receiver under the curve area) using ROCR Library 
but unfortunately, the roc curve is showing a weird graph 
this is the code so far

```
 library(caretEnsemble)
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, savePredictions=TRUE, 
classProbs=TRUE,preProc=c("center","scale"))
algorithmList <- c( 'rpart', 'knn', 'nb')
set.seed(seed)
models <- caretList(Revenue~., data=training, trControl=control, methodList=algorithmList)
results <- resamples(models)
summary(results)
dotplot(results)
bwplot(results)
```

which will result in

```
Models: rpart, nb, knn 
Number of resamples: 30 

Accuracy 
           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
rpart 0.7714286 0.8539916 0.8873016 0.8803097 0.9142857 0.9714286    0
nb    0.7777778 0.8865079 0.9142857 0.9137333 0.9428571 1.0000000    0
knn   0.7647059 0.8055556 0.8431373 0.8450825 0.8857143 0.9166667    0

Kappa 
           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
rpart 0.4776119 0.6618591 0.7490016 0.7345538 0.8127266 0.9378330    0
nb    0.5485893 0.7595388 0.8059150 0.8126149 0.8779422 1.0000000    0
knn   0.3928571 0.5363648 0.6353245 0.6327338 0.7329892 0.8098592    0
```

combing the model with the best correlation

```
set.seed(seed)
stack.glm <- caretStack(models, method="knn", metric="Accuracy", trControl=stackControl)
print(stack.glm)
```

calculating the ROC Curve

```
library(ROCR)
lda.model <- predict(stack.glm,newdata = testing,type = 'prob')
lda.pre <- prediction(as.numeric(lda.model),as.numeric( testing$Revenue))
evl1 <- performance(lda.pre,"acc")
plot(evl1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGx3B.png)

Comment: If you're trying to get to a plot of the ROC curve, I think you need to specify a different measure in your call to `performance`. See the first example in the documentation for that function ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROCR/ROCR.pdf)).